# bn.fit INTEGER() can only be applied to an 'integer', not a 'double'

Tags: r, bnlearn

I'm trying to train a Bayesian network with a mixed model.

```r
wl <- matrix(c("DR", "DT", "LN", "DL", "DL", "DT"), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
bl <- matrix(c("DT", "D", "DT", "DR",  "DT", "DL", "DT", "FT",  "DT", "FS",  "DT", "FC", "DT", "FA", "DT", "LN", "D", "DL", "DT", "CO",  "DT", "BPM25", "DT", "PM10", "DT", "SWS", "DT", "VWD", "DR", "D", "DR", "FT",  "DR", "FS",  "DR", "FC", "DR", "FA", "DR", "LN", "DR", "CO",  "DR", "BPM25", "DR", "PM10", "DR", "SWS", "DR", "VWD", "DL", "D", "DL", "FT",  "DL", "FS",  "DL", "FC", "DL", "FA", "DL", "LN", "DL", "CO",  "DL", "BPM25", "DL", "PM10", "DL", "SWS", "DL", "VWD", "CO", "FT",  "CO", "FS",  "CO", "FC", "CO", "FA", "BPM25", "FT",  "BPM25", "FS",  "BPM25", "FC", "BPM25", "FA", "PM10", "FT",  "PM10", "FS",  "PM10", "FC", "PM10", "FA", "PM10", "VWD", "PM10", "CO", "BPM25", "CO", "DL", "DR", "VWD", "D",  "FT", "D", "FS", "D", "FA", "D", "PM10", "D", "LN", "D", "FC", "D",  "BPM25", "D", "SWS", "D"), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

net <- hc(df, blacklist = bl, whitelist = wl)
graphviz.plot(net)
fit <- bn.fit(net, df)
```

The hill-climbing algorithm works fine. However, when I try to fit the data, it fails wit the

> INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'double'

here is my `str(df)` output:

```
'data.frame':   337676 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ LN   : Factor w/ 15 levels "Alphington","Altona North",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ D    : Date, format: "2019-04-15" "2019-12-29" "2019-12-29" "2019-12-29" ...
 $ DR   : num  33.7 33 33 33 33 ...
 $ DT   : num  381 354 354 354 354 ...
 $ FT   : Factor w/ 2 levels "BURN","BUSHFIRE": 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ FS   : Factor w/ 6 levels "BURNT_1","BURNT_2F",..: 3 3 4 4 4 1 4 2 2 1 ...
 $ FC   : Factor w/ 7 levels "0-9","10-29",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 6 6 ...
 $ FA   : Factor w/ 6 levels "L","M","NA","S",..: 6 2 4 6 6 6 6 6 6 2 ...
 $ CO   : Factor w/ 2 levels "LOW","MED": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ BPM25: Factor w/ 3 levels "HIGH","LOW","MED": 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 ...
 $ PM10 : Factor w/ 3 levels "HIGH","LOW","MED": 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ SWS  : Factor w/ 3 levels "HIGH","LOW","MED": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 ...
 $ VWD  : Factor w/ 5 levels "East","Eeast",..: 3 5 5 5 5 5 5 3 5 5 ...
 $ DL   : num  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 ...
```

And this is a learned network:
[image]

and link to the dataset https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjYX1QIwxaySkngPNn6nvcmL5L0g?e=chehjR

Comment: ... are you able to share enough data to reproduce the error?

Comment: here is a link to the dataset
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjYX1QIwxaySkngPNn6nvcmL5L0g?e=chehjR

Comment: Thanks. okay from a quick test the problem is with the date class variable. For example, excluding it causes things to run as expected `df2 = df[sapply(df, function(x) is.numeric(x) | is.factor(x))]; net = hc(df2) ; f = bn.fit(net, df2)` . I am not sure if it is coerced to numeric in hc but then integer in bn.fit, or if something else is happening dependent on the class of the parent / children variables -- i'll look at it tomorrow. I think this is a bug in bnlearn in as much that it should be stricter in catching user error i.e. you should not be passing a date class variable.

Comment: I think the data type checks get caught out as `typeof(df$D)` returns double (although this is done in th C api [here](https://github.com/cran/bnlearn/blob/0e4d3af6ad579b79bc9959e77385ec6b825ca6fc/src/sanitization.c#L83) hence why it doesn't get caught in hc. There are further checks done in bn.fit where it does get caught. I'll raise a bug report / fix. I don't think date class variables should be accepted and it should be up to the user to decide how they want to treat these variables e.g. discretise it / as Gaussian / build a dynamic net?

Comment: the latest `bnlearn` snapshot (4.7-20210803) no longer accept `Date` or `POSIXct` class variables as input.